# Hochdeutsch und Luthers Bibelübersetzung

Tags: standard-german

Ein Deutscher hat mir einen Grund dafür genannt, warum man in Hannover (und in dessen Nähe) Hochdeutsch spricht. Es habe damit zu tun, dass Luther in diesem geographischen Gebiet die Bibel übersetzt oder gedruckt und „dadurch die biblischen Texte dem einfachen Volk zugänglich gemacht“ hätte. Vielleicht zitiere ihn nicht ganz richtig.

Nach seiner Erklärung wurde das Deutsch durch Luthers Übersetzung quasi *standardisiert*. Aber manchmal setze ich diese Theorie in Zweifel, denn wie groß dürfte der auf die Definition des Begriffes „Hochdeutsch“ ausgeübte Einfluss dieser Übersetzung sein? Wäre Bairisch zu „Hochdeutsch“ geworden, wenn diese Übersetzung in Bayern und nicht in Niedersachsen durchgeführt worden wäre?

Die nicht-rhetorische Frage lautet:

*Gibt es keinen besseren (etwa geographischen) Grund oder Erklärung dafür, dass man in dieser Region Südniedersachsens Hochdeutsch spricht?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Martin Luther kam aus Eisleben, heutiges Sachsen/Anhalt (Mansfelder Land, südöstlich des Mittelgebirges Harz).

> "Seine Sprachform war das [Ostmitteldeutsche](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostmitteldeutsch) seiner Heimat, in dem
>   nord- und süddeutsche Dialekte schon verschmolzen waren. Aber erst
>   durch Luthers Bibelübersetzung entwickelte sich dieser Dialekt zum
>   gemeinsamen Hochdeutsch. Sie gilt daneben dichterisch als große
>   Leistung, da sie bis in den Silbenrhythmus hinein durchdacht war." ([siehe Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luther#Bibel.C3.BCbersetzung))

Es stimmt also, dass sein verwendetes Deutsch zur *Standardsprache* wurde. Der Grund dafür ist leicht ersichtlich: Die Bibel war zu jener Zeit *die* Standardliteratur, die das gesamte Leben in allen Regionen maßgeblich prägte. Seine Bibelübersetzung hatte neben anderen, bereits zahlreich existierenden Bibelübersetzungen den durchschlagenden Erfolg, da sie erstens in einfacher verständlicher Sprache geschrieben war und zweitens Zwischenübersetzungsschritte vermied. Nicht zuletzt hatten auch die politischen Ereignisse der Reformation ihre Wirkung.

Man beachte, der Begriff *Hochdeutsch* hat zwei Bedeutungen ([siehe hier](http://www.wortbedeutung.info/Hochdeutsch/)):

> 1. stilistisch „über“ den Mundarten und der Umgangssprache stehende, genormte Standardsprache im deutschen Sprachraum (Hochsprache)
> 2. Linguistik: Oberbegriff für die hochdeutschen (mittel- und oberdeutschen) Sprachen und Dialekte südlich der Benrather oder der
>      Uerdinger Linie, im Gegensatz zu Niederdeutsch

Spricht man vom *Hochdeutsch* im Zusammenhang mit Luther, meint man die erste Bedeutung.

Comment: Wenn die Übersetzung hypothetisch in Bayern stattgefunden hätte, wäre man evtl. mehr gezwungen gewesen, Verwechslungen zwischen 1. und 2. zu vermeiden, und würde vielleicht heute nicht den Begriff *Hochdeutsch* sondern *Standarddeutsch* verwenden. Allerdings vermute ich, ein begünstigender Faktor war auch, das ein Dialekt gewählt wurde, der von allen anderen nicht zu weit entfernt ist. Bayrisch wäre vielleicht zu weit im Süden gewesen, also zu inaktzeptabel für den stark nördlichen Teil.

Answer (score 11):

Interessanterweise wurde im Raum Hannover, wie in ganz Norddeutschland, ursprünglich Niederdeutsch gesprochen, das sehr anders ist als die heutige Standardsprache. Es hat insbesondere die Umwandlung von langen Vokalen in Diphthonge und von stimmlosen Verschlußlauten in Affrikaten und dann teilweise weiter nicht mitgemacht. So heißt es im Niederdeutschen beispielsweise *hus* (*Haus*), *appel* (*Apfel*), *water* (*Wasser*), *dat* (*das*). So um 1400 herum war Hannover also weit, weit entfernt von dem, was heute Standardsprache ist.

Im 15. Jahrhundert begannen die norddeutschen Städte, sich an der Sprache des Südens zu orientieren. Die Leute – zuerst die städtischen Oberschichten – entschieden sich bewußt, ihr Niederdeutsch aufzugeben und fortan das Hochdeutsch der Südhälfte Deutschlands zu sprechen, das prestigeträchtiger war. Woher das Hochdeutsche im Norden plötzlich dieses Prestige gewann, läßt sich nicht definitiv sagen; wahrscheinlich hat die Wirtschaftsentwicklung dazu beigetragen (Niedergang der Hanse, Aufstieg von süddeutschen Handelszentren), aber auch die bedeutendere Literatur des hochdeutschen Sprachgebiets. – *Hochdeutsch* ist hier übrigens der Oberbegriff für *mitteldeutsch* und *oberdeutsch*, die beiden großen Dialektgruppen der Südhälfte des deutschen Sprachgebiets.

Jedenfalls war schon gegen 1470 das ursprünglich niederdeutsche Halle weitgehend zum Hochdeutschen (genauer Mitteldeutschen) übergegangen, ab 1510 wurde in der städtischen Verwaltung in Berlin für alle Schreiben in andere Städte nur noch Hochdeutsch verwendet. Die meisten großen norddeutschen Städte folgten bis zur Mitte des 16. Jahrhunderts (Bremen, Hamburg, Lüneburg, Stettin usw.). Anfänglich wurde das Niederdeutsche noch gesprochen, vor allem auf dem Land und in der städtischen Unterschicht, und zum Teil auch im internen Verwaltungsgebrauch geschrieben, aber zunehmend als unmodern und rückständig empfunden. Wer etwas auf sich hielt, sprach Hochdeutsch. In der Folge ist das Niederdeutsche bis zum 20. Jahrhundert in weiten Teilen Norddeutschlands praktisch ausgestorben, insbesondere in den Städten gibt es seit langem einfach kein Niederdeutsch mehr.

Die wenigsten von denen, die im Norden nun „Hochdeutsch“ statt Niederdeutsch sprachen, waren in Süddeutschland gewesen oder konnten Sprachunterricht in der heutigen Form nehmen. Der Austausch (auch zwischen den verschiedenen Regionen des mittel- und oberdeutschen Sprachgebiets) fand überwiegend schriftlich statt. Entsprechend entwickelte sich im vormals niederdeutschen Sprachgebiet eine *spelling pronunciation*: Man versuchte alles so auszusprechen, wie es geschrieben war, und verschiedene Zeichen auch mit verschiedenen Lauten wiederzugeben. Mit der „Originalaussprache“ hatte das oft wenig zu tun, beispielsweise waren praktisch im ganzen mittel- und oberdeutschen Gebiet *ö* und *ü* längst in der Aussprache mit *e* bzw. *i* zusammengefallen – wurden aber in der Schreibung noch unterschieden, und deshalb in Norddeutschland auch wieder in der Aussprache.

Erst ab dem späten 18. Jahrhundert gab es Bemühungen, ursprünglich vor allem für das Theater, die Aussprache zu vereinheitlichen und damit eine gesamt-deutsche Aussprache überhaupt erst zu schaffen. Dabei orientierte man sich letztlich an der Aussprache in Norddeutschland. Im Jahr 1898 veröffentlichte Theodor Siebs seine *Deutsche Bühnenaussprache*, die für viele Jahrzehnte die maßgebliche Aussprachenorm an Theatern und später im Tonfilm, Radio und Fernsehen blieb.

Nun rühmen sich die Hannöverschen tatsächlich gern, perfektes Hochdeutsch zu sprechen. Nach dieser Vorgeschichte ist das wenig überraschend: Ihre ursprünglich künstliche Aussprache des Hochdeutschen ist einfach zur Aussprachenorm erhoben worden. Wenn man allerdings genauer hinhört, stellt man fest, daß sie doch nicht so reden wie von Siebs und heute in der Standardsprache vorgesehen. Wie in ganz Norddeutschland spricht man im Raum Hannover kein /ɛː/, das ist mit /eː/ zusammengefallen: etwa *Käse* [ˈkeːzə]. Es gibt Wörter wie *krökeln*, die man im Rest des Landes nicht versteht, und im Umland (nicht unbedingt in Hannover selbst) wird teilweise das /ɪ/ vor /r/ gerundet (z.B. in *Kirche*). Von perfektem Hochdeutsch kann auch in und um Hannover also keine Rede sein. Man kann sogar sagen: Es gibt *überhaupt keine* Gegend in Deutschland, in der reine Standardsprache gesprochen wird.

---

Und Martin Luther? Mit Hannover hatte er nichts zu tun, er lebte etwa 150 Kilometer südöstlich, in Grenzgebiet von Nieder- und Mitteldeutsch. Er hat von 1483 bis 1546 gelebt, der erste Teil seiner Bibelübersetzung wurde 1522 veröffentlicht; zu diesem Zeitpunkt hatte das Niederdeutsche schon viel Boden verloren (siehe die Jahreszahlen oben), Luther hat die Entwicklung also nicht ausgelöst.

Zu diesen Fragen und überhaupt vielen Deutsch-Themen muß ich wieder einmal den *dtv-Atlas zur deutschen Sprache* empfehlen, der einen sehr kompakten Überblick über die Entwicklung der deutschen Sprache gibt.

Comment: Luther hat die begonnene Entwicklung also nicht ausgelöst, aber zusätzlich noch stark begünstigt mit der gewählten Sprachform der Bibelübersetzung.

Comment: Wunderschöne Antwort und Wasser auf meine Mühlen von »Hannover spricht doch gar kein reines Hochdeutsch«. Ich hab gehört, dass in der Vergangenheit das Prager Deutsch als das »reinste« Deutsch gegolten habe, da es bairische und sächsische Einflüsse am meisten vermischt habe. Stimmt das, und wenn ja, könntest du das noch einfügen? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt meiner Meinung nach noch eine andere wichtige Komponente zur Sprachentwicklung: in und um Hannover herum, wie auch nördlich davon war die gesprochene Sprache ursprünglich hauptsächlich Plattdeutsch, was sich sehr stark vom Luther-Deutsch unterscheidet, und eher dem Holländischen ähnlich ist. Im Osten und Süden hingegen war die gesprochene Sprache dem (Luther-) Schriftdeutsch ähnlicher, daher konnten diese Regionen ihren ursprünglichen Dialekt besser beibehalten.